# Error en convertir una imagen a base64 en flutter con ruta utilizando image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

Al utilizar image_picker en su ultima versión, de la siguiente manera:

```
                final XFile? pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(
                  source: ImageSource.camera,
                  maxHeight: 150,
                  imageQuality: 90,
                );
```

Retorno la ruta como he encontrado en algunos ejemplo que he revisado, tomo la imagen con la cámara y con la siguiente parte:

```
File file = File(pickedFile!.path);
                print('Ruta de archivo = ' + file.toString());
```

Busco el path donde se localiza la imagen y obtengo el siguiente mensaje en consola:

```
Ruta de archivo = File: '/data/user/0/com.example.qrcode/cache/scaled_bb1c9502-5b0c-4afd-bfcd-99115bcf788a3760710577154129314.jpg'
```

Tengo entendido que si obtienes la ruta puedes convertir la imagen ya que se localizo en cache pero cuando tomo la ruta, la paso a byte así:

```
List<int> fileInByte = file.readAsBytesSync();
                String fileInBase64 = base64Encode(fileInByte);
                print(fileInBase64);
```

En consola sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si tomo todo la linea y le agrego data:image/jpeg;base64, mas la linea del código en base64 sale algo no se ve la imagen, solo se ve un cuadro algo pequeño, no se que pueda ser ya que no convierte la imagen como debería de ser

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de como muestras la imagen?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero guardarla el string en una base de datos por eso quiero solo el puro string, y lo mostrare en el navegador con angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya vi el problema, tu código es correcto, pero cuando tratas de mostrar la imagen en base64, la consola no te muestra la información completa debido a las limitaciones del método `print`.

Hazlo usando el método `log`, pero necesitas importar esto:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';
```

Luego usas el `log`

```
 log("texto muy grande aquí")
```

Comment: Tienes razón, ya visualice toda la cadena de caracteres gracias a ello, pensé que era algún error de lógica o algo distinto a ello, gracias por tu ayuda.